# Error in javascript function in dynamically generating a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a shopping website so to dynamically generate a modal I am using javascipt, ajax but there is a little problem about it. It does not shows up the modal it show the error everytime.

```
function detailsmodal(id)
{
    var data = {"id":id};
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:<?php echo BASEURL;?>+'include/detailsmodal.php',
        method: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('body').append(data);
            jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which error does it show?

Comment: what is the response you got from the request?

Comment: success does not executes

Comment: everytime error function is executed